# ScrollView throwing an error message

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm using the following code to create views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="PI 12343"
                android:id="@+id/proformo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                    android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="PI 12345"
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="on Dec 2016"
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="4312412412"
                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="ETD:"
                    android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="24 oct 2015"
                    android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="ETA:"
                    android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="09 dec 2014"
                    android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                        android:id="@+id/productName" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="40mts"
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Amount: "
                            android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="200 USD"
                            android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="40 USD"
                            android:id="@+id/rate_value" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to draw a line after displaying al textviews within the viewgroup. The problem that I face is that it throws an error saying `scrollview can have only one direct child`. But Im trying to draw line at the end. How to do that? Also my image view is not visible when I run it on emulator.

Comment: Wrap the Views inside of a LinearLayout so the ScrollView has only the LinearLayout as a direct child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout             
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="PI 12343"
            android:id="@+id/proformo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="PI 12345"
                android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="on Dec 2016"
                android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="4312412412"
                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="ETD:"
                android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="24 oct 2015"
                android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="ETA:"
                android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="09 dec 2014"
                android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                    android:id="@+id/productName" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="40mts"
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Amount: "
                        android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="200 USD"
                        android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="40 USD"
                        android:id="@+id/rate_value" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
         <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>   
   </ScrollView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:paddingButtom="10dp" 
        android:background="#000000">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="PI 12343"
                android:id="@+id/proformo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                    android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="PI 12345"
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="on Dec 2016"
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="4312412412"
                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="ETD:"
                    android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="24 oct 2015"
                    android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="ETA:"
                    android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="09 dec 2014"
                    android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                        android:id="@+id/productName" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="40mts"
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Amount: "
                            android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="200 USD"
                            android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="40 USD"
                            android:id="@+id/rate_value" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: imageview is not visible yet

Answer (score 0):

the error explains itself you cannot put multiple views as direct child to scroll view. You are putting a linearlayout and a view directly inside the scrollview. It can only have a single view as direct child. so enclose your outermost linearlayout and view inside another linearlayout with vertical orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can add background(#000000) attribute and paddingButtom to ScrollView to implement this work,so the last view is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add two separate child inside a Scroll View. that's why it is giving exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="PI 12343"
                android:id="@+id/proformo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                    android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="PI 12345"
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="on Dec 2016"
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="4312412412"
                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="ETD:"
                    android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="24 oct 2015"
                    android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="ETA:"
                    android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="09 dec 2014"
                    android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                        android:id="@+id/productName" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="40mts"
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Amount: "
                            android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="200 USD"
                            android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="40 USD"
                            android:id="@+id/rate_value" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the layout_weight attribute of the ImageView,like this:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```